# How do I programmatically set the connection string for Entity-Framework Code-First?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to write some code that allows me to switch between SQLCE (locally on my dev machine) and full SQL (on AppHarbor). With SQL CE, the connection string is all handled for me, but I have to construct it myself for SQL. My code so far is below, however it gives this error:

> Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

I've been looking online for hours, but all the solutions involve using a "ContextBuilder" class which I can't find (I've installed EF via the NuGet package).

Here's the current code (running at startup via WebActivator):

```
public static void Start()
{
    // Read the details from AppSettings. Locally, these will be empty.
    var databaseHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseHost"];
    var databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"];
    var databaseUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseUsername"];
    var databasePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePassword"];

    // Check whether we have actual SQL Server settings.
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(databaseHost) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(databaseName))
    {
        // Set up connection string for a real live database :-O
        var connectionString = string.Format("metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;"
            + "provider=System.Data.SqlClient; provider connection string='Data Source={0};"
            + "Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2}; Password={3};MultipleActiveResultSets=True'",
            databaseHost, databaseName, databaseUsername, databasePassword);

        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(connectionString);
    }
    else
    {
        // Set a custom database initializer for setting up dev database test data.
        Database.SetInitializer<BlogDataContext>(new BlogDataIntializer());

        // Set the connection factory for SQL Compact Edition.
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you should use the **EntityConnectionStringBuilder** class

```
string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
string serverName = ".";
string databaseName = "AdventureWorks";

// Initialize the connection string builder for the
// underlying provider.
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder =
new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

// Set the properties for the data source.
sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

// Build the SqlConnection connection string.
string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

// Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

//Set the provider name.
entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

// Set the provider-specific connection string.
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

// Set the Metadata location.
entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/AdventureWorksModel.csdl|
                        res://*/AdventureWorksModel.ssdl|
                        res://*/AdventureWorksModel.msl";
Console.WriteLine(entityBuilder.ToString());

using (EntityConnection conn =
new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString()))
{
conn.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Just testing the connection.");
conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got further, but it does on CREATE DATABASE. Installing SQL Express so I can script the DB - but I don't understand what the Metadata property should be set to for Code-First

Comment: Works fine. The metadata property I included must work, even though I've no idea where it's finding those metadata files :D

Comment: usually these metadata are read from the configuration file. In my case i removed them the configuration file and read them from the database.

Comment: I just included "metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;" and it worked, but I don't know if that's because it's not creating the DB (on AppHarbor I can't drop/recreate, so I script it and create manually)

Comment: Ok that is great. I guess everything is working fine with you, right?

Comment: Yep :-) Even works with SQL Express locally when it *does* need to create a DB, so the metadata property seems to be "correct" even though I've no idea where those metadata files exist :)

Comment: These metadata files are generated by Entity Framework dynamically upon the first connection to the database.

Comment: In case anyone wants the source for this answer for further research: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: what about the database username and password ?! where do we put them in this code ?

Comment: You should use the below properties,

sqlBuilder.UserID = "userId";
sqlBuilder.Password = "password";

Answer (score 13):

In  Entity-Framework Code-First use SqlConnection. You cannot use EntityConnectionStringBuilder because in code-first there is no metadata files.

Comment: This helped me figure out that I needed Entity string builder for database first :) +1

Answer (score 8):

You can also set it directly on your context. You have to attach the mdf to the SqlServer instance you want to use first. Not exactly elegant but it worked for me

```
public void DoImportWork()
{
   var ctx = new StatisticsContext(); << your DbContext 

   ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXP;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXP\MSSQL\DATA\StatisticsData.mdf"";Integrated Security=True";

   ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
}
```

as usual EF will auto-generate everything when you add your first row to the context.

Answer (score 0):

This code will come handy for creating `connection string` with `Entity Framework`

```cs
    public string GenerateEFConnectionString(string serverName, string dbName,string ModelName,string userName,string password)
    {   
        // Initialize the connection string builder for the underlying provider.
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = dbName;
        //sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        sqlBuilder.UserID = userName;
        sqlBuilder.Password = password;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
            new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        // Set the Metadata location.
        entityBuilder.Metadata = string.Format("res://*/{0}.csdl|res://*/{0}.ssdl|res://*/{0}.msl",ModelName); 
        return (entityBuilder.ToString().Replace("\"","&quot;"));
    }
```

It can be called from a set of parameters as

```cs
    GenerateEFConnectionString("srv","db","mod","vinodsrivastav","nopassword");
```

to generate a `connection string` like this

```
metadata=res://*/mod.csdl|res://*/mod.ssdl|res://*/mod.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=srv;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=vinodsrivastav;Password=nopassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;
```