# Keyword not supported: "data source" initializing Entity Framework Context

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I'm initializing Entity Framework Object context, and this gives me the keyword not supported error:

`metadata=res://*/MainDB.csdl|res://*/MainDB.ssdl|res://*/MainDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Workspace\vs\Leftouch\Leftouch.Web\Data\Leftouch.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;`

I took the connection string directly from web.config which was working, and modified only the path to the file (which I set dynamically), and instead of using the default value, used this connection string explicitly. What could cause this error?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003085/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-connection-string-for-entity-framework-code-fi for a different approach

Comment: I don't know who came up with this `metadata=res:`, then `res=somethingelse` with `&quot;` all over the place syntax - but they should be really glad they aren't in the same room as me right now :-/

Comment: 2018 .Net EF Core similar syntax error - providerName was not needed by a SqlClient connection string.  Also no quotes or ticks in string for EF core.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

The real reason you were getting this error is because of the `&quot;` values in your connection string.

If you replace those with single quotes then it will work fine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/rickandy/explicit-connection-string-for-ef

(Posted so others can get the fix faster than I did.)

Comment: If you are passing in the connection string to the ObjectContent class, make sure that it has single quotes. If you are getting the connection from the .config file, then it is okay to use the &quot; escape sequence.

Comment: For those of you not familiar with how XML works, `&quot;` is an escape sequence for a quotation mark because it is a reserved character in XML.

Comment: System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder made it for me, thank you.

Comment: The blog link in your post gave me awareness about `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` class. Thank you. +1.

Answer (score 38):

I fixed this by changing `EntityClient` back to `SqlClient`, even though I was using Entity Framework.

So my complete connection string was in the format:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: The above change will potentially lead to  (as in my case) the following error "The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development"

Comment: You can comment throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException() in OnModelCreating(), but it looks like a dirty workaround

Answer (score 14):

This appears to be missing the `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` bit. Sure you got the whole thing?

Comment: Ok, that was another attribute, forgot that one. Added it now it is `metadata=res://*/MainDB.csdl|res://*/MainDB.ssdl|res://*/MainDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider name=System.Data.EntityClient;provider connection string=&quot;{0};App=EntityFramework&quot;` and it now says key not found: provider name. I've also  tried `providerName=...` instead of `provider name=` too, but no luck.

Comment: Well, I started to create it using the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` class, and weirdly, it's working now. But I still have no idea why it wasn't accepting my string, even with your additions.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, renaming LinqPad.exe.config to LinqPad.config solved this problem.

Comment: This is Microsoft, anything can be happened !

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What has Linqpad to do with the question and how can renaming an executable ever be helpful?

Comment: Well this particular error occured with Linqpad in my case and doing this resolved it.  And I didn't rename the executable. I renamed the .exe.config to .config.

Comment: Anyway, it's a very specific scenario. It only adds noise as it doesn't *explain* anything,

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `Data Source` and not `DataSource` in your connection string. The space is important. Trust me. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

Just use \" instead ", it should resolve the issue.