# Move Identity context (ApplicationDbContext) to my data access layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity

I have a web application using asp.net mvc 5 decoupled architecture n-layers.
I have 4 layers:

- Entities (all entities using code first).
- Data (layer of data access and generic repository) reference to Entities.
- Bussiness (login of bussiness) reference to Entities and Data.
- Presentation (mvc 5 web application) reference to Entities and Bussiness.

In my web application i am using identity authentication. The problem is this, I need to create a unique context in which identity mix tables with my classes of Entities layer. How do I pass the context to the Data layer and to add custom entities of Entities layer?

Comment: What do you mean by identity context?

Comment: I call identity context to the class that inherits of IdentityDBContext, in which is introduced the connection string, the DBSet, etc.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I still have not found the solution.

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24739362/1237854