# ASP.NET Identity reference in a Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm trying to create a relation in two models, Courses and Assignments:

```
namespace MyWebApp.Core.Models
{
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z]{3}\d{3}", ErrorMessage="Invalid Course ID")]
    [Display(Name="Course ID")]
    public string CourseSeq { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Course")]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Professor")]
    public string Professor { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyWebApp.Core.Models
{
public class Assignment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Assignment")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Due on")]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The UserApplication : IdentityUser (from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity) class is defined in IdentityModels which is created by default when choosing a MVC template. I've created another project in my solution (MyWebApp.Core) which will hold the Models. I'm getting an error when creating a prop (user ) which will relate the model to the user tables. Basically Assignments relates to Courses which relates to Users. For some reason I can add the using directive in the .Core project, it doesn't find it in references. I've also moved the default IdentityModels from MyApp.Web.Models to MyApp.Core.Models, which created a couple error due to missing references. Does it make sense to move the default IdentityModels to a class lib .core, and change it's namespace or is it better to keep the identity Models in .wed

Comment: what's the problem so far ... ? do u have any compiling  error ?

Comment: Well, once I move the IdentityModels to MyWebApp.Core, I get at least 17 errors, almost all having to do with missining refs/assemblies. Here is my repo, you can take a look at the way I have the solution set up. I reverted back to a previous working version where the IdentityModels is in .Web

Comment: https://github.com/lf-hernandez/MyAssignStore

Comment: From what I understand it's a good practice to place all your Models in a separate class file. And have the Views and Controllers in the actual web app.

Comment: ok if you moved  you identity models to the Core project you will need to install 3 packages in the Core projected "EntityFramework", "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" and "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" and it will be fine ...

Comment: Yes. So, when I tried, I was able to add a reference to EF. But for some reason Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and MIcrosoft.AspNet.Identity.EF did not show up. The only refs I found were Microsoft.AspNet.Scafolding and M.AN.Scafolding.EF; ... I apologize about the abriviatiions

Comment: from tools >> NuGet Package Manager >> Package Manager Console ... and any package you need u can do that .... Install-Package PACKAGE_NAME -version VERSION HERE ...... -version is not mandatory but if you need a specific version u can get it like that

Comment: I actually have the package installed already, for some reference I can't add the ref to .Core( It is a Class Library not a ASP.NET MVC Web App)

Comment: I don't understand what u mean by "I can't add the ref to .Core" ?

Comment: So when you right click references -> Add Reference -> upper right corner search bar - > I enter Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and nothing shows up. I can't add those to references to .Core....but they are present in .Web as well as installed in the solution

Comment: you won't add reference to them like that ... open the Package Manager Console and write Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core ... click ENTER. this will add the reference automatically.

Comment: I think you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446919/moving-asp-net-identity-model-to-class-library?rq=1

Comment: Please note that the tag [tag:model-view-controller] is intended for questions about the *pattern*. You've already tagged it with the relevant ASP.NET implementation, so you don't need to (and shouldn't) add the pattern tag.

Answer (score 0):

Packages were installed only in .Web.
The correct way to have added the references was by right click on the Solution -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Installed -> Click on Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework [manage] and select .core project.