# Keyword not supported: 'metadata'. when trying to create a dynamic connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I am trying to set the connection string dynamically in my database first MVC web applications. This is the code that I've come up with but it keeps erroring with

```
Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.
```

I'm aware that there are other similar qustions on Stackoverflow but none of the solutions have solved my problem
This is the code that I'm using

```
public partial class DevTS_mtEntities : DbContext
{

    public DevTS_mtEntities(string conn)
    {

        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "metadata=res://*/Setup.Questions.Questions.csdl|res://*/Setup.Questions.Questions.ssdl|res://*/Setup.Questions.Questions.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=<server>;initial catalog=DevTS_mt;user id=<user>;password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\"";

    }

}
```

Comment: this the edmx generated connection string.  It contains a connection string that you need to pull out of it.  This is your connection string "data source=<server>;initial catalog=DevTS_mt;user id=<user>;password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"

Comment: @Fran I tried that and it now says 'The 'data source' keyword is not supported.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup Entity Framework For Dynamic Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440698/setup-entity-framework-for-dynamic-connection-string)

Comment: See the duplicate.  Don't set it yourself in the constructor, call the base constructor to do that.

Comment: @Fran I already tried it but I got another error 'The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development. '