# Can I use SetDefaultConnectionFactory for Database first or Model first

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I'd like to use `DbConfiguration.SetDefaultConnectionFactory` feature, which is to set the connection string "used to create connections by convention if no other connection string or connection is given to or can be discovered by `DbContext`".

But it seems like this can be used with Code-first only. If used in my project it goes to `DbContext.OnModelCreating` and throws `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`.

Are there any similar solution that can be used with DB-first or Model-first?

My code:

```
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbContext() : base("ConnStrName") {}
    public DbContext(string connStr) : base(connStr) {}
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuidler modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintenionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}

public class EF6CodeConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public EF6CodeConfig(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new ConnectionFactory(configuration));
    }
}

public class ConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOfConnStr)
    {
        var str = GetConnStr(nameOfConnStr);
        return new System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection(str);
    }
}
```

And config EF:

```
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new EF6CodeConfig(configuration));
```

Background about my situation: I'm creating a new .NET Core microservice referencing some old DLLs that used EF6. But EF6 cannot find the connection string from .NET Core appsettings file. So I need that fallback that `SetDefaultConnectionFactory` provides.

I have a work-around, but doesn't look good:

```
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    private static string GetConnectionString(string connStrName)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConnectionString) ? connStrName : ConnectionString;
    }

    public DbContext : base(GetConnectionString("name=ConnStrName")) {}
    ...
}
```

And set the connection string myself:

```
DbContext.ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to change connection string in database first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508798/is-there-a-way-to-change-connection-string-in-database-first)

Comment: No, I'm using .NET Core, it uses `appsettings.json` instead of `web.config`. Even if I add one EF6 still can't find the connection string. Using a different constructor can apply for new code but code from previous DLL that are using the default constructor won't work.