# No constructor with a connection string in Entity Framework datacontext

Tags: .net, entity-framework-5

I am using `Entity Framework 5.0` for my project. I looked on the internet and I saw that for the entity framework data context there was another constructor that had a string parameter for the connection string.

On my generated `data context` I don't have such a constructor. I looked into the base `DbContext` and it has such a constructor.

Was the code generated wrong? I generated the code from a database. Could this be the cause?

Turns out that I can edit the code generation template file to add the new constructor. Now I have added the new constructor. The file is a MyDataContext.tt file under your edmx model. There you have c# code mixed with template code. You can copy the no argument constructor from there and paste it bellow. Then you can change it and add a string argument to it and pass that argument to the DbContext constructor like this : base(myString).

Comment: Can you post the codes to make the difference more clear ..?

Comment: What is stopping you from adding it manually?

Comment: Also, DbContext is "Code-First". If you have an existing database, the typical usage is "Database-First".

Comment: @flem With EF5 even database first generates the dbcontext classes for you. It uses T4 files

Comment: @scartag. I thought db-first used `ObjectContext`? Did it change in EF5?

Comment: @flem going forward we are advised to use dbcontext and with EF5 when you generate the classes, it uses T4 to give you that. although you can still access objectcontext from dbcontext if you need to.

Comment: the DbContext which is the base class for my datacontext has the property ObjectContext inherited from the interface IObjectContextAdapter that the DbContext implements. But it's implemented private so I actually have to cast the db context to the interface to access it. I know that there is a entityconnection string builder class but it too much for my requirements.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add one as needed.

Check the generated file and add an overloaded constructor.

```
public YourContext(string connectionStr)
        : base(connectionStr)
    {


    }
```

Probably better to define this in a partial class though, as every generation will require you to manually add it each time.

Comment: I believe I can also edit the .tt file but I don't know if this file is a autogenerated too.

Comment: tested and changed the .tt file adding a new constructor in it. works now

Comment: @Alecu: I had the same problem and did the same thing: good to know!

Comment: I agree with scartag it is better to define it in a partial class, as every-time your code is generated you will loose your customisations. And it's easier to do that than edit the tt files.

Comment: NOTE: In order to set the ConnectionString programatically, make sure you don't format it like the one in web.config or app.config. That one will contain &quot; which needs to be changed to single quotes, or you will get  a most unhelpful error message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997035/keyword-not-supported-data-source-initializing-entity-framework-context . Either that, or use the  EntityConnectionStringBuilder.