# How to set sensitive data

Tags: c#, database

When I'm creating Entity Data Model, there's a question in the wizard like
"would you like to include sensitive data in connection string?"
I am choosing 'No, I'll set it in my application code'.
So my question is, how to set that?

And the other problem is, that I NEVER had a model constructor with connectionstring parameter so I can't do something like that:

```
MyEntity model = new MyEntity(connectionstring)
```

I have only non-parameter constructor.

Comment: This:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170118/how-to-in-code-supply-the-password-to-a-connection-string-in-an-ado-net-entity-d

and this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182091/no-constructor-with-a-connection-string-in-entity-framework-datacontext

really helped me.