# decrypt connectionstring with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, encryption

I've made a class called Crypto to encrypt en decrypt connectionStrings. This class works perfectly.

The idea is to get the encrypted connectionstring in the config file:

```
    <add name="MyConnString" connectionString="KsY+XWC0GnsepTlVu0Z3BU4r0hCAfgrCl/gbqlasndFmCjq0iiTNC7r0JySqm4BtSnSktE20EfDe9F3cDZTaQqwUgmdQTrxBc8cp5HhC9G6PEyzXIVzy2HMyOIH45yTQ9j70uMPV7TUazlnvzRDYnrKJwpgHNQehjMovgkWKCfZji1kQNVN7/61yvdrv+d6KpQKU5Al5W2QKkI7wxYzvJ4vMwH6XoCk1RnulKFKvaMExWtjQTh4XOy2Wo4M9UHKM/FuhjrsxsBg4JgcUcPGfrJZortFmmeDYt7D7QP6/I9HlIrmR4K42/hKSb/ZGiDV9szK6A/V1u9p5qctqFCui7Dx0AKkvUqFIWOWQHtvivV0R/PW8+R1bxsNkr6wUK6A5uPyghJmP4Qv0VI3vW8z0Tw==" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

the problem is where and how do I decrypt the connectionstring (the decrypt method works)
I've tried making these adjustments to the designer class within the edmx file:

```
  public partial class KlantenBITEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        public static string DecryptedConnectionString
        {
            get { return Crypto.DecryptFromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"].ToString()); }
        }
```

And in the constructor I tried to pass the decrypted connectionstring :

```
 public KlantenBITEntities(): base(DecryptedConnectionString,"KlantenBITEntities")
        {

            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }
```

If I to this I get this error:
Keyword not supported:'data source'

I've encrypted the whole entity framework connectionstring (with csdl-,ssdl-,msl-file etc..) Could this be the cause?

Any help with finding a proper way to decrypt the entity framework connectionstring is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
[KeyWord Not Supported: data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997035/keyword-not-supported-data-source-initializing-entity-framework-context)

the problem was &quote . Replacing it by single quotes solves it.