# Keyword not supported: 'data source' entity framework error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

My Connection String:

I have host my mvc4 application in windows azure with entity framework 5 model-first and i got this error. any one please help me.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997035/keyword-not-supported-data-source-initializing-entity-framework-context) question it may have something to do with your connection string.

Comment: I have replace ' quotes , but after that getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments and as previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997035/keyword-not-supported-data-source-initializing-entity-framework-context), this is because you have `&quot;` in your connection string.

You should replace these with single quotes for it to work.

Comment: <add name="HIPAAtrekDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.HIPAAtrekDB.csdl|res://*/Models.HIPAAt‌​rekDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.HIPAAtrekDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider  connection string='data source=tcp:g80tw0l2qo.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=DatabaceName;user id=fdffddfsf;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=E‌​ntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />   Like this but solve my issue.

Comment: @Ashok Patel - Try removing the last ' before the " that you have at the end of the connection string (just after App=EntityFramework)

Comment: @Ashok Patel - Looking back I think my last comment was wrong as I now see the other single quote.  I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: I think Azure is support only Code-first entity. i have try all the thinks but i have not solve my this issue.