# Keyword not supported Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting Keyword not supported error with some encrypted value like below  :-

```
Keyword not supported: '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'.
```

and then when I tried to pinpoint the issue I am getting the below error

```
"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(IDictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, IList`1 validKeywords)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, IList`1 validKeywords)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Local()"
```

I am not sure, how to solve this, below is my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccessObjects.TestModel.csdl|res://*/DataAccessObjects.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/DataAccessObjects.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Test_dev;initial catalog=Test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I am not sure what is going wrong ?

Can anyone help me out in this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't provide any code to help us figure out what you're doing, let alone where it could be going wrong. Are you just letting EF create the model, and it's throwing this error?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997035/keyword-not-supported-data-source-initializing-entity-framework-context). &quot, SqlProvider, etc.

Comment: I am using a database first approach, and recently I have added a new column in my table, so when I refresh my edmx and do a run custom tool on the TestModel.context.cs and the corresponding .tt file, I am getting the above errors.