# "Cloning" EntityConnections and ObjectContexts in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

(This used to be a 2-part question, but since the second part is literally the important one, I decided to split this into two separate posts. **See [Using Serialization to copy entities between two ObjectContexts in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12604585/1426433) for the second part.**

I want to create a fairly generic "cloner" of databases for my entity model. Also, I might need to support different providers and such. I'm using `ObjectContext` API.

I am aware of [this question already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6003101/1426433) and the [EntityConnectionStringBuilder MDSN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) example, but I need to know if there is a programmatic way to obtain the values to initialize the `Provider` and `Metadata` properties of an `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`?

```
using (var sourceContext = new EntityContext()) {
    var sourceConnection = (EntityConnection) sourceContext.Connection;
    var targetConnectionBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

    targetConnectionBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = GetTargetConnectionString();
    targetConnectionBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"; // want code
    targetConnectionBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl"; // want code

    using (var targetContext = new EntityContext(targetConnectionBuilder.ConnectionString)) {
        if (!targetContext.DatabaseExists())
            targetContext.CreateDatabase();

        // how to copy all data from the source DB to the target DB???
    }
}
```

That is, is there a way to fetch the

- `"System.Data.SqlClient"`
- `"res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl"`

from somewhere and not use literal values?

Comment: Would you mind changing the 'enchilada' term to something more internationally-understandable? :)

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whole+enchilada :D I want the whole thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Metadata

You should be able to use `res://*/` to tell Entity Framework to search for all .csdl, .ssdl and .msl files in the calling assembly. Alternatively, use `res://assembly full name here/` to search in a specific assembly. Note that both these syntaxes will load all found files, which works fine until you have several .edmx in the same assembly, resulting in several CSDL/SSDL/MSL files (an .edmx file is basically a concatenation of those three files). More information [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx).

If you want more control, use [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx) to list all resources in a given assembly, and match the .csdl/.ssdl/.msl resources manually together, then build your metadata string manually from those resource names.

#### Provider

The provider can be found in the SSDL file in the Provider attribute of the root node. Once you have the correct file name, Use [`GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx) and read the file as XML. The code should look like this:

```
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EntityModel.ssdl")) {
  XDocument document = XDocument.Load(stream);
  string provider = document.Root.Attribute("Provider").Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, at least an answer for this finally!