# ASP.NET - Can I use or select different DBs in an entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm fairly new in Entity Framework and web API. I'm trying to `GET` data from a table. But the table is going to be selected from different databases. So, there's multiple databases with the same tables and I need to select which database (I'm thinking `[Fromuri]`) I need to get the tables from. Right now I only have one database connected. Not sure if I need to add it all as a connection string or is there an easier way.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    using (var MGC = new GC_BranchNameEntities())
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var jsonIDSA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MGC.INV_LIVE_IDSA, Formatting.None);
        try
        {
            return Ok(jsonIDSA);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest("Error occured when retreiving IDSA data " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can I do something like `using(var MGC = new SelectdatabaseEntitiesusingParam)` something like that?

Comment: Do the databases have the same structure (tables, relations, columns)? If it is, using a diferent connection string for the data context would open connection to that database. [It is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003085/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-connection-string-for-entity-framework-code-fi) to create connection string for entity framework from code.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik Yep, Completely identical. Except for the data of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `DbContext` constructor overload that takes a connection string or name of a connection string as a parameter, and others that accept an existing `DbConnection` object.

Update:

Add a new constructor to your `DbContext` derived class, passing the parameter to the base constructor:

```
public GC_BranchNameEntities( string nameOrConnString ) :
    base( nameOrConnString )
{
}
```

Then, when instantiating your `DbContext`, pass in the name of the connection string to use (one defined in your config file) or an actual connection string.  Alternatively, you can also create a constructor overload that accepts an existing `DbConnection` object (similarly to the `nameOrConnString` parameter) and pass that to the base constructor.

Comment: Can you explain further? I'm looking at my DBcontext.cs right now but I'm a bit lost

Comment: Done that, how will I select my DB from my Get method? How will I instantiate the database I want from Uri?

Comment: On my base if I want to just point it to the name I go base("name=" + nameOrConnString) ?

Comment: base(name) will first look in the app.config for a connection string defined with that name. if there is none (with that name), it will check the string provided if it is a connection string.